# MySQL LIKE with Unicode

Tags: mysql, unicode

I have two tables with Unicode characters. Both of them are using collation = utf8_general_ci.

However, if I try to join or even query for a word in one table on the other table, they don't match, even if they look exactly the same.

I copied this straight out of my query...

```
SELECT * FROM `SBLGNT` where B like '%ἀμήν%'; --doesn't work (copied word from other table)

SELECT * FROM `SBLGNT` where B like '%ἀμήν%'; --works (copied word from this table)
```

Comment: Specify COLLATE in the comparing condition explicitly.

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-collate.html

Comment: There are different diacritics above *Letter Eta* in the strings: `ή` (U+1F75,  *Greek Small Letter Eta With Oxia*) versus  `ή` (U+03AE,  *Greek Small Letter Eta With Tonos*). [Unicode normalization](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/) could help…

Comment: when encountering strange behaviour with string comparison, it is often helpfull to convert the strings to hex to see if they just look similar, but aren't similar on the byte level

Comment: It was the diacritics. Thank you JosefZ! I'm working through the Unicode normalization like that you provided now.

Answer (score 0):

One has GREEK SMALL LETTER ETA WITH OXIA (hex E1BDB5); the other has GREEK SMALL LETTER ETA WITH TONOS (hex CEAE)

The Collation `utf8_general_ci` is rather basic; it apparently treats them as the same.  I suggest you change to `utf8_unicode_520_ci` if it is available in your version.  If using MySQL 8.0, I will provide different advice.

Change the collation of the connection and the column(s).  Then they will be treated as "equal".